# pagination custom post type with multiple WP_Query loop

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress

after adding the function of pagination to **Functions.php** and recall it in **template-product-listing.php**
there is nothing shown in result.
I have a big problom with this...

could you find and resolve the problem?

thnx

```
        <article class="row">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div id="single-head" class="sixteen columns">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php if (has_excerpt()) { the_excerpt(); } ?>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <nav id="portfolio-filters" class="sixteen columns">
                    <a href="#filter" class="active-item" data-filter="*"><?php _e('Show All', 'ci_theme'); ?></a>
                    <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'hide_empty' => 0
                    );

                    $skills = get_terms('product-category', $args);
                    ?>
                    <?php foreach ( $skills as $skill ) : ?>
                        <a href="#filter" data-filter=".<?php echo $skill->slug; ?>"><?php echo $skill->name; ?></a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </nav><!-- /portfolio-filters -->
            </div>

            <div id="portfolio-items" class="row">
                <?php $ci_product_query = new WP_Query('post_type=product&posts_per_page=4'); ?>
                <?php if ( $ci_product_query-> have_posts() ) : while ( $ci_product_query->have_posts() ) : $ci_product_query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php $item_skills = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product-category');    ?>

                <article class="<?php ci_e_setting('product_columns'); ?> columns <?php foreach ( $item_skills as $item_skill ) : echo $item_skill->slug.' '; endforeach; ?> columns portfolio-item">

                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>" class="fb">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('ci_portfolio_slider', array('class'=>'scale-with-grid')); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-desc">
                        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        <p class="desc"><?php echo mb_substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 70); ?>...</p>
                    </div>
                </article><!-- /portfolio-item -->

                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            </div><!-- /portfolio-items -->

            <?php get_template_part('part', 'call_to_action'); ?>

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <div class="pagination">
        <?php wp_pagination(); ?>
        </div>
        </article>
```

Comment: I think you must be more specific what you tried, and what you see. Nobody will have the time to re-create your case and debug it for you (at least nobody you dont pay).

Comment: thanks dear. but I've copied hole file to be more detailed!
may be you're right . it was my first question here and I'm beginner...

Answer (score 0):

if your sure there is a post_type called products and there is posts in it...

try:

```
 <div id="portfolio-items" class="row">
            <?php $ci_product_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'product', 'posts_per_page'=> 4); ?>
            <?php if ( $ci_product_query-> have_posts() ) : while ( $ci_product_query->have_posts() ) : $ci_product_query->the_post(); ?>
```

You know you are starting a new wp_query for every post in have_posts() ? you might want to rethink what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: thnx for your answer . but nothing changed .